# e=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: sync for class org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture

Tags: java, netty

I'm a front end hacker that's working with a bunch of smart java people at the moment. On my dev machine, I keep on getting this error when I make a POST request to my dev environment, for a speech API we're building. This error only happens for me though, everything is fine in production, and other people's dev env.

```
ERROR speech.symphony - speech/ e=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: sync for class org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture instance=52efd7ad-bcf5-4077-ba52-845a494273cd
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: sync for class org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField(Reflector.java:271)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:300)
    at wit.netty$netty_stream.invoke(netty.clj:102)
    at wit.netty$netty_stream.invoke(netty.clj:62)
    at wit.integration.google$stream_asr_BANG_.invoke(google.clj:62)
    at wit.speech.symphony$chunks__GT_diag$fn__43088$state_machine__5906__auto____43089$fn__43091.invoke(symphony.clj:131)
    at wit.speech.symphony$chunks__GT_diag$fn__43088$state_machine__5906__auto____43089.invoke(symphony.clj:131)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:945)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:949)
    at wit.speech.symphony$chunks__GT_diag$fn__43088.invoke(symphony.clj:131)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have no idea what this means. Any explanation on what you think might be going on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're including a field in your request (JSON?) that doesn't appear on the target Java class in the server. This is most likely due to a version mismatch relating to the class mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just guessing here but maybe you have netty 3 on the classpath but netty 4 is needed ?